# Android Gradle plugin 3.0.1 - Error converting bytecode to dex

Tags: android, gradle, guava

Upgrading from Android Gradle 2.3.3 to 3.0.1 I was getting the following build error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/base/internal/Finalizer;
```

This appeared to be an issue with **Guava** being included as an implementation, by my app; unit tests (Robolectric) and Instrumented Tests.

I resolved this build error by excluding Guava from Robolectric:

```
testImplementation ("org.robolectric:robolectric:$rootProject.ext.roboelectricVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

And for Instrumented tests, if I set the minSdkVersion to 21 it would resolve this build error there, via:

```
minSdkVersion 19
// Gradle plugin 3.0.1 broke instrumented tests with error: "Multiple dex files define ...Finalizer". Setting minSdkVersion = 21 clears this error
gradle.startParameter.taskNames.find {
    if (it.contains("AndroidTest")) {
       minSdkVersion 21
    }
}
```

However, when I run a build for a device < 21, then I still get the build error.

So, the issue appears to be with **Guava with Multidex support prior to Android 5.0**.

Anyone else experiencing this issue and/or have suggestions for working around it?

Comment: Do you have `multiDexEnabled true` in your `defaultconfig` section of your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Yes. I have multiDexEnabled true in the defaultconfig section.

Comment: And I have the mulitdex support library included to support devices prior to Android 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue did seem to be with Guava. Taking a guess that it is the size of that library and the build having an issue with fitting it in the main DEX (the dex required for loading and initializing the app).

I switched out Guava for this [lightweight Stream library](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) and was able to build successfully for all devices.